# Stored procedure that accepts an id as a parameter - how to execute for multiple ids list?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Hi I have the following stored procedure that works for a single id (field22):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_procedure`(IN f22  INT)
BEGIN

UPDATE Table1 p join Table2 b set p.f1= (p.f1-  (LEAST(p.f2,b.amount)*coalesce((select rate from CurrencyExchangeRate where   fromCurrency=b.currency and toCurrency=p.currency and date(date)='2017-01-  15'),1))) ,
 p.f5= (p.f5- (LEAST(p.f2,b.amount)*coalesce((select f6 from   CurrencyExchangeRate where fromCurrency=b.currency and toCurrency=p.currency and   date(date)='2017-01-15'),1))),
p.f7= (p.f7- (LEAST(p.f8,b.amount)*coalesce((select rate from    CurrencyExchangeRate where fromCurrency=b.currency and toCurrency=p.currency and date(date)='2017-01-15'),1))) where status!=2 and p.id=b.f13 and b.id=f22;


UPDATE Tabl2 SET status=2, f1=3,changeDate=now() where id=f22 and status!=2;


INSERT INTO Table4 (type,f1,f2,date,f3,amount,f5,f6) select 11,2,tr.id,now(),tx.f11,tr.f12,tr.amount-tr.f13+tr.f14,tx.id from Table6 tr join  Table7 tx where tr.id=tx.f77 and tr.id=f22;

END
```

I would like to execute this stored procedure for a known list of ids i have:

```
  [1,22,443, 2112 ...];
```

Whats the quickest way to go about it?

Comment: Found my answer with the selected answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326775/call-a-stored-procedure-for-each-row-returned-by-a-query-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

If you can pass in the string `"1,22,443", then you construct the query:

```
SET @sql := CONCAT("... IN (", f22, ")...");
```

then `PREPARE` it and `EXECUTE`.

Not clean, but it should work.

If there is only one element to send in, the `IN` will still work fine.  (An empty string would lead to a syntax error.)